# Read and Play .wav Files in Assembly

Tags: assembly, x86, wav

I wanna write an assembly x86 program in which I read and play a .wav file. I have googled the structure of a typical .wav file and found that there are some data available in the subchunk section.

I have understood the following and I wanted to make sure whether or not it is correct so that I could start coding:
The sample rate is simply the rate at which the original analog signal is sampled to digital values (probably representing frequences). I guess I have nothing to do with this value when playing the .wav file. Byterate is the rate at which I have to send out bytes (somehow related to the "bitrate" which can be found in the "properties" of any sound file.).

So for example I have to turn the speaker on, send out the byte, wait for some time -which is somehow calculated by having the frequency of the clock and the byterate(the number of bytes to send out in a duration of one second)- turn the speaker off and again wait for some time.
Is this correct?

And I don't know what I can do with 2 channel .wav files. Are channels speakers of different ports?

And one last thing is that I don't know how to calculate the amount of time to turn the speaker on or off - idle loop the CPU- having the byterate at hand. Coz different instructions take different clock cycles to accomplish.

Comment: What possible reason is there to write such a program in assembly language?

Comment: I'm obliged to do so, as my prof. gave me the project.

Comment: So why are you asking internet strangers for help instead of asking your professor directly?

Comment: What OS? If Windows/*nix, are you supposed/allowed to use its services? WAV is a Windows format...

Comment: Use the [waveOut API](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms713505(v=vs.85).aspx)

Answer (score 0):

WAV files are linear samples derived from a codec. You must play them back at the same rate unless you interpolate or decimate them.

As I recall, the WAV file format uses interleaving for multiple channels.

In order to decode the file you need the width of the samples (number of bits), and the sampling frequency (Hertz), and the number of channels present.

What OS is this?

Comment: Windows it is. Yes in the beginning of the file, there is a section in which we can find all of the above information. But I simply don't know what to do with the channels. When sending the bytes out, what difference it makes if the byte belongs to the right channel or the left one?

Comment: That doesn't necessarily make a difference and that's easy to swap. You can also sum the two channels together and play the sum out both channels converting it to mono. This is an odd program given Window's support for WAV. I'd imagine doing this will require you to load a buffer for the sound device, and a timer which reflects the duration of the buffer's playback.

Comment: I'm real sorry acting like a noob, but I don't get it. Are the sample bytes the one bytes to send out? If yes, are channels of different ports; so that I have to send one bytes of the right channel to a different address than the ones of the left?

Comment: Let's say for example, the header indicates 16-bit, 48KHz, stereo. This means that the file contains (after the header) 16-bit samples in the format of: the first sample is the left channel, the second sample is the right channel. You continue reading the file in this manner until it's done. If you read the entire file in, you can then use 16-bit registers to hold samples, movsw instructions, and word ptr (or just word) prefixes.

Comment: Using 48KHz, this means each sample is 20.8333 us of time. Therefore, if you write 1000 samples into the sound buffer, you need to come back and write more at 1000 * 20.8333 us = 20.8 ms. I haven't played with the Windows sound card in a long time, but devices such as these use "ping pong" buffers. That is, you load one buffer (ping) while the other buffer is playing (pong). Usually the device has a status query to find out how many bytes can be written at any given moment. Your samples will be consumed at the sampling rate. You have to be back in time to give it more samples.

Comment: Thank you very much for your time :) I'm gonna search and read about the stuff you said more.